# How does user input fit into Apple's MVC pattern?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns, model-view-controller, uiscrollview

I'm a little confused about input processing in regards to [Apple's MVC pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html). According to Apple, your objects should be divided into model objects (which handle the data), view objects (which display stuff), and controllers (which bind the two and also process events and input). However, many of Apple's native UIKit views — UIScrollView, UIControl objects, etc. — do all the input processing themselves, possibly letting their controllers know about it via delegates and data sources. This really confuses me. In my mind, the sturdiness of the MVC triad depends on both the model and view being fairly dumb (and thus easily swappable). When all the OS-level event complexity is centralized in the controller, you have a very nice separation of concerns. On the other hand, adding input processing to the view seems to turn it into a sort of controller of its own.

Am I missing something here? What's the correct way to think about this?

Answer (score 1):

User Input is part of the *View* in the MVC pattern.  They directly interact with the user and provide their data, either on request or through delegation, to a *Controller*, which might then use that input to affect changes to the *Model*.

Comment: But according to Apple's official page on the matter:


"The controller object might interpret the user input in some application-specific way and then either may tell a model object what to do with this input—for example, "add a new value" or "delete the current record"—or it may have the model object reflect a changed value in one of its properties. Based on this same user input, some controller objects might also tell a view object to change an aspect of its appearance or behavior, such as telling a button to disable itself."

Comment: @Archagon I would assume Apple are using the term *user input* in that sentence to mean "data from the user interface".

Answer (score 0):

"Dumb" and "easily swappable" are not necessarily the same thing.

Buttons contain a lot of functionality that we don't want to rewrite in every single controller: tinting of the image to indicate highlighting, allowing for cancellation if the tap strays a certain distance before touch-up, etc. Scroll views contain a lot of physics.

In other words, "which display stuff" is a mischaracterisation of view objects. UIView -- the base class -- just provides event data, but subclasses provide higher-level data such as "the button was tapped" or "the scroll view decelerated to a stop".

Answer (score 0):

One thing to think about is your perspective.

When most of us code, our Model is a data object (maybe backed by files or databases, etc), our View is a `UIView` (possibly setup/configured in Interface Builder) and our Controller is the `UIViewController`.

What if you weren't coding an app though? What if your world was a `UITableView`? You can still have a basic MVC separation. Your Model is represented by the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, your View still a `UIView` with it's setups and configurations and your Controller is the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. All the pieces there and even separated, the separation is just different than when using a `UIViewController`. You can see a practical example of the separation a data change. When you the data in the data source protocol nothing happens. You have to call a `reloadData` method on Controller bit for the table to realize data was changed.

The smaller the item, the harder it will be to see the MVC pattern. A "button" would be a lot harder to use if it was broken into 3 different objects, but you can use MVC patterning inside a single object to create well encapsulated. A `UIButton` has it's Model in the form of a both public and private properties, a View (`UIView` still) and a Controller which is bunch of code that accepts events and makes modifications to the View and/or Model as appropriate.